# How to dynamically extract a part from XML tag name using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an input XML from which I want to extract an integer part specifically from a node (not the node value). The integer can be of any digits. How to do it?

I have tried many ways including name() but not able to get the desired output.
This is my input XML

```
<input>
<name-40-perc>10</name-40-perc>
<name-130-perc>20</name-130-perc>
</input>
```

The XSL should extract the value '40' from

```
<name-40-perc>
```

and '130' from

```
<name-130-perc>.
```

Please note that these values(40,130) can vary, they are not fixed.
Help me with an XSL code.

Comment: Please help me with a proper XSLT code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you know that the value you want is between the (only) two hyphens in the name of the element, then it can be rather easy.The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(name(), '-'), '-')" />
            </value>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <value>40</value>
  <value>130</value>
</output>
```

---

Another option is to extract the digit characters using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(name(), translate(name(), '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
```